# Triple integral set up using cylindrical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

Set up an integral in cylindrical coordinates to evaluate $\iiint_{E} x y d V$ where $E$ is the region enclosed by the cone $z=2-\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$, the cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$, and the $x y$ plane.

My try:

The region $E$ is shown below:

[image]

So the triple integral in cylindrical coordinates is:

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{2 \pi} \int_{r=0}^{1} \int_{z=0}^{2-r}(r \cos \theta)(r \sin \theta) r d z d r d \theta$$

Is this set up correct?

Comment: Your record is correct for region inside cylinder. Note, that due to symmetry around $yz$  (or $xz$) plane integral value is zero.

Comment: could you explain in detail?

Comment: 1. There are two regions bounded by $z=0$, $x^2+y^2=1$ and $z=2-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. First (enclosed in both cylinder and cone) is defined by inequalities: $0\leq r \leq 1$, $0\leq z \leq 2-r$. Second (enclosed in cone but outside of cylinder) is defined by inequalities: $1\leq r \leq 2$, $0 \leq z \leq 2-r$. If your original problem includes word "enclosed" then only first region is appropriate and then your integration limits are correct.

Comment: 2. Both regions are symmetrical around $xz$ plane and around $yz$ plane. For every $dV$ with coordinates $(x,y,z)$ is corresponding $dV$ with coordinates $(-x,y,z)$, then integral can be divided into two integrals, one for positive $x$ and one for negative $x$. Integrand $xy$ is odd function of $x$, then integrals for positive $x$ and for negative $x$ have the same absolute values but opposite signs. Then sum of integrals for positive $x$ and for negative $x$ is zero. It is somethig like integral of $x$ from $-a$ to $a$: $\int_{-a}^a x\, dx=\int_{-a}^0 x\,dx+\int_0^{a} x\,dx=-A+A=0$.